# Gradle: use dependency from local AND from repo

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have two projects, let's call them Application and Library, where Application depends on Library. Normally Library is developed in its own project and published to a repository (our internal JFrog); and in Application's build.gradle it is specified as dependency.

So far so good. But once in a while if I am working on both, I would like Application to depend on the Library code as checked out locally, so that I don't have to build the Library, publish it to the repository, change the version in build.gradle of Application and rebuild.

What is the best way of achieving that (if this behavior can be parameterized in Gradle via some environment variable or such would be even better)?

Answer (score 1):

Build the `Library` code with maven, or gradle and publish it to your local m2 repository.

In the repositories section of your `Application` project, include `mavenLocal`

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to avoid that separate step; it does avoid pushing it to a remote repo but other than that the same steps apply. Ideally I'd just build the Application and it'll know to build Library if needed locally. (Bonus of course would be for this setup to work in an IDE too but one thing at a time).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add a line to settings.Gradle of the Application project:

```
includeBuild “path_to_Library_project”
```

Then Gradle will automatically use your local copy of Library to resolve the Library dependency.